Bezout identity with relatively prime coefficients
The Bezout lemma says that given an ordered list of integers $x_1,\dotsc,x_n \in \mathbb Z$, one can find an associated list of coefficients $a_1,\dotsc,a_n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a_1x_1+\dotsb+a_nx_n = \gcd(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)$. The coefficients aren't unique.
In the case $n=2$, you automatically see that $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$ (otherwise the gcd would be smaller). I'm wondering: for $n > 2$, can I always find some choice of the $a_i$ such that $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$? I'm specifically asking about two fixed coefficient indices here, not just that some pair of coefficients somewhere be relatively prime.
For example: consider the relatively prime triple $x_1=6, x_2=10, x_3=15$. In this case, you might randomly encounter an equation $-24x_1+10x_2+3x_3=1$. But then the first two coefficients aren't coprime. Instead, we can write $-4x_1+x_2+x_3=1$, which fits my condition.

What’s the point to fix indices $1$ and $2$, if the order of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is not fixed?

$x_1=5, x_2 =2, x_3=7$ and $a_1=2; a_2=6$ and $x_3=-3$ yields $2\times 5 + 6\times 2 - 3\times 7 = \gcd(5,2,7$.   While $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=\gcd(2,6)=2$.  Not sure I understand the point of your questions.

And I don't think $a_i$ need to have any relatively prime pairs.  If $a_1 = -6; a_2=-15; a_3=10$ we  can have $x_1=4,x_2=3,x_3=7$ to have $a_1x_1+a_2x_2 +a_3x_3=\gcd(4,3,7)$

@fleablood It's more "does there exist a solution set which has $\gcd(a_1, a_2) = 1$" rather than "does ALL solution sets have $\gcd(a_1, a_2) = 1$".  $\quad$ So in your specific example of $ x_1 = 5, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 7$, we have $ 3\times 5 - 2 \times 2 + 0 \times 7 = 1$, hence the answer is yes.

@Aig really the order of the $x_i$ is fixed, I edited to make this clearer. Perhaps it would have been better to start with a set of integers of the form $u,v,x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ and ask about the coefficients on $u$ and $v$.

@EthanDlugie   best to type in an example or two with actual numbers, with commentary, I suggest an $n=3$; also, for something simple with just integers, learn one of the easy languages to check realism for your conjecture. Also, there is an answer below by someone reliable, print it out  (or a screen capture)  to go through it, perhaps ask in comment below the answer if you have concerns

Let's do that trick where we prove a stronger statement by induction on $n\ge2$:

Given $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\Bbb Z$ and $y_n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, there exist $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\Bbb Z$ with $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$ and $a_1\ne0$ and $\gcd(a_1,y_n)=1$ such that $a_1x_1+\cdots+a_nx_n=\gcd(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

(There's only one $y_n$, not a sequence of them; but labeling it with the subscript will help us when writing the inductive proof.)
Base case: Let $n=2$, and WLOG assume that $\gcd(x_1,x_2)=1$ by dividing through. The solutions to $a_1x_1+a_2x_2=1$ are of the form $a_1=\alpha+x_2k$ and $a_2=\beta-x_1k$ for some integers $\alpha,\beta$; every such pair $(a_1,a_2)$ is automatically relatively prime as the OP noted. Consider any prime $p\mid y_2$. Note that it's impossible for $p$ to divide both $\alpha$ and $x_2$ since $\alpha x_1+\beta x_2=1$; consequently, there are (at least $p-1$) residue classes $k\pmod p$ such that $a_1=\alpha+x_2k$ is not divisible by $p$. Applying this to every $p\mid y_2$ and using the Chinese remainder theorem, we can find residue classes $k\pmod{y_2}$ such that $a_1=\alpha+x_2k$ is relatively prime to $y_2$; we simply choose $k$ so that $a_1\ne0$ to finish the proof.
Inductive step: Let $n\ge3$, and again WLOG assume that $\gcd(x_1,\dots,x_n)=1$. Set $g=\gcd(x_2,\dots,x_n)$, so that $\gcd(x_1,g)=1$. By the induction hypothesis (ignoring some of its conclusions), there exist $b_2,\dots,b_n$ with $b_2\ne0$ such that $b_2x_2+\cdots+b_nx_n=g$. Now apply the $n=2$ case with $x_2=g$ and $y_2=b_2y_n\ne0$: we obtain $c_1,c_2$ with $\gcd(c_1,c_2)=1$ and $c_1\ne0$ and $\gcd(c_1,b_2y_n)=1$ such that $c_1x_1+c_2g=1$. This last equation means that $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_nx_n=1$ with $a_1=c_1$ and $a_2=b_2c_2,\dots,a_n=b_nc_2$; in particular, $\gcd(a_1,y_n)=\gcd(c_1,y_n)=1$ and $\gcd(a_1,a_2) = \gcd(c_1,c_2b_2)=1$, which completes the proof.

Fantastic, thank you!
